# Way to optimize huge SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a very long query which return some records if the column id_cat matches user search.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (id_cat = 50 OR id_cat = 51 OR id_cat = 52...) up to some high numbers.
```

In above case the query gets real big which increases it time for response.

I need to optimize that because response time get close to 15 seconds (basically it search through all of the categories).

How should I do this?

First of all i was thinking of building a query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id_cat = (50 OR = 51 OR = 52))
```

Which should decrease the number of sql words but it doesnt work like this (returns null instead of rows). And I dont have any more ideas.

Do you have any suggestions about how to handle that?

Comment: Consider building a separate table as a list of all the ids, and then comparing against that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, build the query using `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE id_cat IN (50, 51, 52, . . .);
```

MySQL optimizes `IN` with constant values.  Without an index, there is still a full table scan.  So, I also recommend an index on `table(id_cat)`.

Comment: Thank. This was the answer i was searching for.

Comment: And if you can turn at least some of those into a BETWEEN query, it becomes easier to read

Comment: @NevilleKuyt unfortunately in that case BETWEEN would not work for me.

Comment: 'OR' is optimized into `IN`.

Comment: @RickJames . . . By any chance, do you have a reference for that?  I can find the reference that `IN` lists are sorted (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in), but not that `OR` is converted to `IN`.  Based on benchmarks I've seen comparing them, this has not been true in older versions of MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yeah, really old versions did not seem to have that optimization.  See if this suffices:  `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ... OR ...; SHOW WARNINGS;`  Meanwhile, not that we are talking only about the same column compared to constants.